# PHP date_create failing when trying to use timestamp from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

i'm just trying to find out why i keep getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: flsrfc
```

now $flsrfc is set like so:

```
if (date_create($flstart)) {
   $flsdt = date_create($flstart);
   if ($flsdt) {
      $flsrfc = date_format($flsdt, "Y-m-d\TH:i");
   } else {
      $flsrfc = date_format(date_create(time()), "Y-m-d\TH:i");
   }
}
```

Now the problem i'm having is attempting to set a datetime-local input with the formatted time i'm trying to get. Here is the code for that and where the error says its coming from. My guess is the date_create function isn't working but i have no friggin idea why.

```
$HTMLOUT .= '<input name="fls" value="'.$flsrfc.'" size="30" type="datetime-local" />';
```

I made sure $flstart was getting the data from the DB and it is here's the code for it:

```
$flstart = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query("SELECT value FROM config WHERE name = 'flstart'"))[0];
```

I've read many of the manual pages and docs for php trying to find out why, i tried strtotime on the timestamp, no go, i also tried forcing it into an integer also same problem. Could someone lease point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: What column type is `value`? What is the actual value? [The docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) describe the formats `date_create()` can parse.

Comment: value is a VARCHAR, due to the fact that the table holds multiple kinds of data.

Comment: What you posted won't work for the query. You didn't pass a connection to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that if `date_create` fails, `$flsrfc` never gets set. You should rewrite that code as:

```
if (($flsdt = date_create($flstart)) !== false) {
    $flsrfc = date_format($flsdt, "Y-m-d\TH:i");
} 
else {
    $flsrfc = date("Y-m-d\TH:i");
}
```

Note that you can simplify the `else` portion by just calling `date` as its default input is the output of `time()`.

In terms of why `date_create` is failing, that would depend on the format of the data in your table. If you are storing it as a MySQL `date` or `datetime` type, there should be no problem with it. Otherwise, you may need to use `date_create_from_format` with an appropriate format parameter to match what is stored in your table.

Comment: It's stored as a Unix Timestamp, i'm just trying to convert that into a date, then format that date into the datetime-local format.

Comment: @BrianSykes in that case you can simply use `$flsrfc = date("Y-m-d\TH:i", $flstart);` The `date` function takes a unix timestamp as its second parameter

Comment: @BrianSykes Not the mysql it won't `mysqli_query("SELECT`, you left out the connection for this.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner didn't notice that - was focussed on the date part. But I guess that must be working...

Comment: @Nick If they say it works, then it must work. Who am I to argue, *right?* Heh!

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner see no evil, hear no evil... :-)